# Angular lifecycle hooks outside component

Tags: angular, angular5

We are looking for a way to register or listen to Angular life cycle hooks outside the component loaded through a route.

Right now a component has to implement interfaces like AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit, OnInit to hook into the life cycle...

We would like to be able to hook to life cycle events outside the route component. The reason is that we are building a framework where we don't want to enforce a base class for all components.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this is possible, you can have a control on children components using ViewChild() and Output() to communicate together.

You don't need to implement angular lifecycle, as you can control actions manualy. Here is an example of what you can do from app.component let's say :

in html you'll have your child component like :

```
<app-child #refChild (onStateChange)="execParentFunc($event)"></app-child>
```

in ts simply :

```
@ViewChild('refChild') myChildComponent: any;
```

then you can execute function from your parent

```
this.myChildComponent.childFunction();
```

finally you can also catch children changes using your Output()

```
childFunction() {
    // process things...
    let newValue = 'something';
    this.onStateChange.emit(newValue); 
}
```

==> this will run your execParentFunc($event) where $event = newValue in this case

Comment: No look we don't control the child component. We are making a third party library with some hooks. The component is loaded through routing. We just want to hook to that component loaded through a route without enforcing the consumer of the library to provide base class, events. The component is loaded into the router-outlet;